# Convert file in PHP to readable values

Tags: php

I normally don't mess with files like this so I may not be asking the correct question for providing the correct content.

I am attempting to open a file in PHP and extract a value from it.

So far I am able to open the file in Notepad++, convert to HEX and then use this website to convert the HEX into the correct number:
http://www.scadacore.com/field-applications/programming-calculators/online-hex-converter/

When I var_dump the value of the file I get characters that look like this:
��������j+���� ���

Is there a way I can replicate the method above in PHP to convert that.

Please let me know any additional information you might need to answer this question!

Thanks!

Comment: Did you try `file_get_contents()` functions?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php ?